# AngularJS drop down list quandry

Tags: angularjs

This code works

```
<select ng-model="connectionsDropDown" ng-options="campaign as campaign.title   
   for campaign in campaigns" ng-change="OnConnectionCampaignChanged(connectionsDropDown)">
 </select>
```

The newly selected value is passed to `OnConnectionCampaignChanged`.

However, there is a blank entry at the start of the drop down list.

Some googling told me that I could remove it by adding

```
track by connectionsDropDown
```

However, when I try

```
<select ng-model="connectionsDropDown" ng-options="campaign as campaign.title   
   for campaign in campaigns" ng-change="OnConnectionCampaignChanged(connectionsDropDown)
    track by connectionsDropDown">
 </select>
```

`OnConnectionCampaignChanged` receives the current value, not the newly selected one.

How do I reconcile the two?

I want:
 - a drop down list with no blank entry
 - to be able to preset the selected value when switching to that view
 - to pass the selected value to `OnConnectionCampaignChanged` when he use chooses another entry

Comment: I agree with the answer provided by @JBNizet, but I would go one step further and ask why you are adding the `track by` clause on the `ng-change` event, instead of the `ng-options`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where you got that `track by` trick, but it does look like a nasty workaround rather than the proper solution.

To understand why a blank option is present, you have to put yourself in the shoes of angular. Let's say your select is

```
<select ng-model="selectedFruit" ng-options="fruit for fruit in fruits">
```

That means: *display all the `fruits` as options in the select box, and select the one which is `===` to `selectedFruit`*.

Now what happens if `selectedFruit` is null, undefined, or just not any of the fruits? What should Angular select as option? It can't select any of the fruits, so it adds a blank option and selects that one.

Corollary: if you don't want a blank option, you have to make sure that the selected fruit is always one of the displayed fruits.

In your case, make sure that `$scope.connectionsDropDown` is referencing one of the objects in `$scope.campaigns`.

Comment: Thanks (+1). That answers my first point. What about the other 2?

Comment: The second point is answered: you need to make sure that the controller populates $scope.connectionsDropDown with one of the objects in $scope.campaigns. And the third point should work fine as well.